# Mapping of $w = z^2$ transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Show, indicating corresponding orientations, that the mapping $w = z^2$ transforms horizontal lines $y = y_1$, $(y_1>0)$ into parabolas $v^2 = 4y_1^2 (u + y_1^2)$, all with foci at the origin $w = 0$.

I am confused as to how to go about doing this. If I write the transformation $w = z^2$ in terms of x and y components, we get $u = x^2 - y^2$ and $v = 2xy$ for $ w = u+ iv$  ans $z=x+iy$, I am not sure if doing this is helpful, as I do not know what to do with the horizontal lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $y=y_1$ in your equations. Square the equation for $v$. Eliminate $x^2$ and you'll obtain the result.

Answer (score 3):

Let $z=x+iy$. The transformation $w=z^2$ becomes
$$w=x^2-y^2+2ixy=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
Hence we identify
\begin{cases}
u=x^2-y^2\\
v=2xy 
\end{cases}

If $y=y_1$ (a horizontal line), we get
\begin{cases}
u=x^2-y_1^2\\
v=2xy_1 
\end{cases}

Squaring $v$:
$$v^2=4x^2y_1^2$$ 
but from the equation of $u$:
$$x^2=u+y^2$$

Therefore
$$v^2=4x^2y_1^2=4(u+y^2)y_1^2$$ 
which is the parabola mentioned.